# Accessibility and Javascript: load dynamic content or show & hide?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I am relatively new to Accessibility standards in my Front End code.

**The question I have:**

- For ***accessibility***, is it better to load all HTML content initially and show/hide it, via a "hidden" attribute?
- Or can I dynamically load the content and fill it with the appropriate attributes?
- And if so, what attributes do you recommend I add to the content to notify the user that the content has been updated and/or changed?

**For example:**
I have a navbar with some buttons/tabs that load the appropriate content.  I can load all content and then show/hide is, similar to below:

```
 <nav>
  <div class="tabs" role="tablist">
    <button
      id="tab-1"
      role="tab"
      aria-controls="tab-content-1"
      aria-selected="true"
      <!-- onClick={show/hide associated content} -->
    >
      Tab-1
    </button>
    <button
      id="tab-2"
      role="tab"
      aria-controls="tab-content-2"
      aria-selected="false"
      <!-- onClick={show/hide associated content} -->
    >
      Tab-2
    </button>
  </nav>

  <div>
    <!-- Content for Tab/Button #1, preloaded and hidden/shown from button click -->
    <section
      id="tab-content-1"
      role="tab-content"
      aria-labelledby="tab-1"
      hidden
      >
      Tab Content-1
    </section>
    <!-- Content for Tab/Button #2, preloaded and hidden/shown from button click -->
    <section
      id="tab-content-2"
      role="tab-content"
      aria-labelledby="tab-2"
      hidden
    >
      Tab Content-2
    </section>
</div>
```

Or I can dynamically load the content via the tab/button click

```
<nav>
  <div class="tabs" role="tablist">
    <button
      id="tab-1"
      role="tab"
      aria-controls="tab-content-1"
      aria-selected="true"
     <!-- onClick={load appropriate content and HTML } -->
    >
      Tab-1
    </button>
    <button
      id="tab-2"
      role="tab"
      aria-controls="tab-content-2"
      aria-selected="false"
      <!-- onClick={load appropriate content and HTML } -->
    >
      Tab-2
    </button>
  </nav>

  <div>
    <!-- Dynamically load the associated Tab Content via Javascript Here
    <section
      id="" => dynamically set 'id'
      role="" => dynamically set 'role'
      aria-labelledby="=" => dynamically set 'arria-labelledby'
      >
      // Dynamically set Content
    </section>
    -->
</div>
```

Comment: Which A11Y standard/spec are you interested in complying with?

Comment: I haven't used every assessability software there is out there. However, the few I have used don't play well with loading data dynamically. An example would be facebook, they will read the page, but once you scroll down it will add more content into it. But the software nevers knows to start reading again and when you manually start it, it would read from the top again. If you use tabs and hide and show it, the software will read it all, while it is technically hidden, the software typically doesn't care. Although that depends on the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should use CSS display:none rather than aria-hidden to hide contents. The attribute aria-hidden should only be used in very specific situations.
I suggest to make a search on when you should and shouldn't use aria-hidden, and why it is so. Many questions already cover the topic well.

Back to your initial question, in terms of accessibility only, it doesn't change much if the content is just made visible or if it is loaded.

Use an aria-live region to tell that the content is loading, in case it may take a while to load.
However, don't use aria-live for the updated/new content itself, especially if it is long and/or contains focusable elements.

Deciding whether you should show/hide or dynamically load is mostly not a question of accessibility. It depends much more on initial and subsequent load times, as well as the level of responsiveness you expect at which moment.

Comment: I think you've mixed up "aria-live" with "aria-busy". aria-live should be used to every content that could be changed at anytime, e.g. if content will be dynamically loaded and is not visible at initial page load. aria-busy instead is calling the screenreader that in this region content is currently loaded.

Comment: @sandy: no, I didn't mixed up. It doesn't bring much to have a long portion of text such as an entire article under aria-live, because it is read in one go and we rarely read an entire article in one go without any pause or interruption. For long portions of text, it's much more useful to move focus.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't make sense to put long textes into aria-live. My point was just the information you wrote: "Use an aria-live region to tell that the content is loading [..]". Here I think you ment "aria-busy" instead of "aria-live".